# Why does URL based tracking require the global site tag installed on all pages?

Tags: google-ads

The [*About conversion tracking* → *How conversion tracking works*](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1722022#howitworks) help page has [*Setting up Conversion Tracking video series, part 1 of 2; creating conversion actions*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49bdV-OspYU) embedded.

On [0:20](https://youtu.be/49bdV-OspYU?t=20s) it says the following:

> **URL Based Tracking**
>
> 1. Create URL based conversion action in Google Ads
> 2. Download "Global Site Tag" code
> 3. Place tag on all pages of your website

If the tracking is URL based, why can I not just install the tracking code only on the page I need tracked, e.g. the order confirmation page that shows after successful payment?

Installing it on other pages seems unnecessary and redundant, seeing that because it's URL based, the tracking shouldn't be triggering on those other pages anyway